# Radio buttons are not getting selected when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have  radio buttons arranged in a table

```
<input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
```

In Chrome it is possible to select radio buttons – but not able to unselect them. [Which I understand as a standard behavior]

In IE it is not allowing me to select the radio buttons at all. [Tested in IE9].

I tried various approaches like giving `name` and `value` - but didn't get it resolved. Any idea how we can fix it?

```
<html>
<table id="tblValidContainers" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 200px;
                    background-color: #E5DBE2; margin-left: 80px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="Heading3" style="width: 120px;" align="center">
                                Container ID
                            </td>
                            <td class="Heading3" style="width: 80px;" align="center">
                                Receive
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
<tr class="Normal">
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
           <div class="divContainerIDWrapper" name="a" value = "a"> ~~3957515 </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
    </td>
 </tr>

<tr class="Normal">
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
           <div class="divContainerIDWrapper"  name="b" value = "c"> ~~3957514 </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
    </td>
 </tr>

<tr class="Normal">
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
           <div class="divContainerIDWrapper"> ~~3957513 </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
    </td>
 </tr>

<tr class="Normal">
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
           <div class="divContainerIDWrapper"> ~~3957512 </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
    </td>
 </tr>

<tr class="Normal">
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
           <div class="divContainerIDWrapper"> ~~3957511 </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
    </td>
 </tr>

<tr class="Normal">
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
           <div class="divContainerIDWrapper"> ~~3957510 </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
    </td>
 </tr>

<tr class="Normal">
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
           <div class="divContainerIDWrapper"> ~~3957509 </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-left: 5px">
            <input type="radio" class="containerRadio">
    </td>
 </tr>

       </tbody>
  </table>
 </html>
```

Comment: You can't _"unselect"_ a radio button. If you want that functionality, you'll need a checkbox.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/g69Pr/) with your code snippet above and it appears to work fine in Chrome and in IE 9+. Could you explain, based on the fiddle what it is or is not doing that you would like it to do?...

Comment: I'm sorry but is it not supposed to be in a <form> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is what I did to resolve the issue.

1. Added `name` property to all the radio buttons
2. Made sure that the names are distinct for each radio button. [Since I need to select multiple radio buttons at once, based on the requirement - though the intention of `"radio" button` is not to do so]

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button) says:

> A radio button or option button is a graphical control element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of options, an exclusive or.

Etymology

> Radio buttons were named after the physical buttons used on older car radios to select preset stations – when one of the buttons was pressed, other buttons would pop out, leaving the pressed button the only button in the "pushed in" position.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're trying to do is a `checkbox` that has a look and feel as a `radio-button` am I wrong?

If so, the checkbox four on this [page](http://www.paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css) might be what you're looking for, with a different CSS.

And, [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css-style-checkboxes/)'s the whole demo of all checkboxes he has made.

I added a possible example of [this other page](http://www.css3.com/implementing-custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-css3/) I found. Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ry7qc/).

**HTML**

```
    <h3>CSS3 Custom Checkbox</h3>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="check1" name="check" id="check1">
        <label for="check1">Checkbox No. 1</label>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="check2" name="check" id="check2">
        <label for="check2">Checkbox No. 2</label>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 500px;
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
label:before {
    background-color: #aaa;
    bottom: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
}
.checkbox label:before {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    color: #f3f3f3;
    content: "•";
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unselect radio buttons. That's because they're used if you want the user to select either option1 or option2 or option3 but prohibit selecting multiple values or leaving it empty (e.g. in case of selecting a Gender).
See [Specification at w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio):

> when one is switched "on", all others with the same name are switched "off".

To unselect "male" if "female" is selected, you have to tell the browser that the radios belong to the same group. That's done by adding the name-attribute:

```
<input checked type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
```

if you wish to give the user the possibility of boxes he can check/uncheck as he likes (e.g. "want to receive our newsletter?"), you should use type="checkbox".

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons get their name from the old-style car radios where you physically pushed one of a group of buttons to change the station.  You can only listen to one station at a time, so only one radio button can be pressed at a time.

"input type="radio"> defines a radio button. Radio buttons let a user select ONLY ONE of a limited number of choices" [see [Radio Buttons](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)]

Answer (score -1):

Everything is correct you just need to add `name` attribute to all radio buttons. All of them should have the same `name`.

Example:

```
 <input type="radio" name="one" class="containerRadio">
 <input type="radio" name="one" class="containerRadio">
```

`Radio` button are meant to provide functionality of selecting only one at a time. If you want to select multiple, you have to use `checkbox`.

Example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="two" class="containercheckbox">
 <input type="checkbox" name="two" class="containercheckbox">
```

Comment: Radio button are meant to provide functionality of only one at a time. If you want to select multiple, you have to use `checkbox`

Comment: Just use `<input type="checkbox" name="two" >`

Comment: "Radio Buttons
<input type="radio"> defines a radio button. Radio buttons let a user select ONLY ONE of a limited number of choices"